# Change Text Size Python

Tags: python, text, fonts

When I copy for example text from libre office or word, it copies the font and the font size, is there a way, that I can input my text in python and change these parameters? For example I want to increment the font size with a value of 5, so a text, with the text size of 10 would be 15 pt ...

```py
# Here an example 

def increment(text, increment_size):
    # Should return the text, but the font size incremented of the value inputed ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: click]

I don't know if you're talking about this but you can try settings.